# C# Action<> with Func<> parameter

Tags: c#, action, func

I have the following method that I can't figure out correct syntax to call:

```
public T GetAndProcessDependants<C>(Func<object> aquire, 
    Action<IEnumerable<C>, Func<C, object>> dependencyAction) {}
```

I'm trying to call it like this:

```
var obj = MyClass.GetAndProcessDependants<int>(() => DateTime.Now, 
    (() => someList, (id) => { return DoSomething(x); }) }
```

Edited:
thx everyone, you guys helped turned on a light bulb in my head. here is what i did:

```
var obj = MyClass.GetAndProcessDependants<int>(
            () => DateTime.Now,
            (list, f) => 
            {
                list = someList;
                f = id => { return DoSomething(id); };
            });
```

not sure why i even an issue with this. it's one of those days i guess..

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at the description above, it looks like the call should be:

```
var obj = MyClass.GetAndProcessDependants<int>(() => DateTime.Now,
    (seq, fun) => { /* do something with seq and fun */ });
```

The key is since you are passing an `Action` that takes a `Func`, the caller is (most likely) going to be the one passing that `Func` into your `Action`.  So you just specify how that `Func` is applied to the sequence passed in (if I'm reading the prototype correctly).

Answer (score 3):

Your lambda syntax is totally wrong.

You need to create a **single** lambda expression with two parameters:

```
(list, id) => DoSomething(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

Right now the function is only accepting a single argument, when it asks for two!

You need to accept a list argument, such as `(list, id) => {}`

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj = MyClass.GetAndProcessDependants<int>(
    () => DateTime.Now, 
    (someList, id) => DoSomething(x)
);
```